# Ignoring hyphen in case insensitive dictionary keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a case insensitive dictionary in asp.net/vb.net like this:

```
Dim caseInsensitiveDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Single)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

it holds values like this

```
one hundred, 100
one hundred one, 101
one hundred two, 102
```

I want that if a user tries to find a value like this:

```
Response.Write(dictionary("ONE-hundred").ToString)
```

he gets 100 but right now it gets exception because dictionary keys don't have hyphon '-'. Which method do i need to override.

please suggest

Comment: Why don't you simply add `ONE-hundred,100` as well?

Comment: Does this mean that I need to add two keys for each number ? one hundred and one-hundred for 100 ?

Comment: And four keys for one hundred one (or one-hundred-one or one-hundred one or one hundred-one...) (Actually that last one's a bit of a stretch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either add `ONE-hundred,100` as well to the dictionary(the easiest approach) or build a custom `StringComparer`:

```
Class CaseInsensitiveIgnoringStringComparer
    Inherits StringComparer
    Private caseInsentiveComparer As System.StringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
    Public Property IgnoreList As IList(Of String) = Nothing
    Public Property ReplaceWith As String = " "

    Private Function Replace(original As String) As String
        If IgnoreList Is Nothing OrElse IgnoreList.Count = 0 Then
            Return original
        Else
            For Each s As String In IgnoreList
                original = original.Replace(s, ReplaceWith)
            Next
            Return original
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overloads Overrides Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer
        Return caseInsentiveComparer.Compare(Replace(x), Replace(y))
    End Function

    Public Overloads Overrides Function Equals(x As String, y As String) As Boolean
        Return caseInsentiveComparer.Equals(Replace(x), Replace(y))
    End Function

    Public Overloads Overrides Function GetHashCode(obj As String) As Integer
        Return caseInsentiveComparer.GetHashCode(Replace(obj))
    End Function
End Class
```

testing

```
Dim comp = New CaseInsensitiveIgnoringStringComparer() With {.IgnoreList = {"-", "+"}, .ReplaceWith = " "}
Dim caseInsensitiveDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Single)(comp)
caseInsensitiveDictionary.Add("One hundred", 100)
caseInsensitiveDictionary.Add("One hundred one", 101)
caseInsensitiveDictionary.Add("One hundred two", 102)

' normally following both lines would cause exceptions '
Dim n100 = caseInsensitiveDictionary("ONE-hundred")
n100 = caseInsensitiveDictionary("oNE+Hundred")
```

Comment: I've upvoted the other answer because it doesn't repeat the `.Replace("-", " ")` code, even though a VB answer makes more sense to a VB question.

Comment: @Douglas: the other answer does not work since it replaces with empty string instead of white-space.

Comment: Good point, fixed. (Since it was DRY, the fix was on just one line, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself )

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a custom IEqualityComparer.

something like this:

```
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return FixString(x).Equals(FixString(y), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    private string FixString(string x)
    {
        // replace hyphens
        return x.Replace("-", " ");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return FixString(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then use that class in the dictionary:
    Dictionary x = new Dictionary(new MyEqualityComparer())

Comment: Pretty much what I was about to put, but change `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @Rawling what the difference between InvariantCultureIgnoreCase and OrdinalIgoneCase ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow I only made this comment because you've used `Ordinal` rather than `InvariantCulture` in your own code - I'm not 100% sure of the difference myself.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am getting Declaration Expected error at  : IEqualityComparer<string>

Comment: Right, should've replaced with " ". Douglas already fixed it. Thanks.